# Spark Kafka Data Consuming Package

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I tried to consume my kafka topic with the code below as mentioned in documentations:

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,") \
  .option("subscribe", "first_topic") \
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

and I get the error:

```
AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".
```

So i tried:

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 ...
```

to install the kafka package and it's dependencies. but I get this error:

```
21/06/21 13:45:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'File file:/home/soheil/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/... does not exist'.  Please specify one with --class.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

what should I do to install this package?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting here is not related to Kafka

`file:/home/soheil/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/... does not exist`

This is referencing your `HADOOP_HOME` and/or `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` variables on your PATH that Spark depends on. Check these are configured correctly and that you can run the [Spark Structured Streaming WordCount examples that use Kafka](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/sql/streaming/structured_kafka_wordcount.py) before running your own scripts.

```
$ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 \
     structured_kafka_wordcount.py \
     host1:port1,host2:port2 subscribe topic1,topic2
```

The next part `Please specify one with --class.` is saying that the CLI parser failed; probably because you mistyped the `spark-submit` options or there is a space in your filepaths, for example